# Shading in Math Mode?

Tags: math-mode, shadows

Is there any macro or package known to shade equations in math mode like the image below?

[image]

I achieved this by using [IguanaTex 1.54](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/) in `PowerPoint 2010`, and then shade the text box as usual. I could use snipping tool and take snips of the formulae from PowerPoint, but I would like to make this by LaTeX directly, if possible. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @HenriMenke It doesn't seem to be straightforward to extrapolate from the dupe solution (which creates shadows for text in `tikzpicture` environment) to displayed equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like I'm drunk...

```
\startMPpage
for i = 0 upto 50:
  numeric n; n := i*.005;
  draw outlinetext.b
    ("$f:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}; f(x) = \log_a x,$")
    (withcolor n[white,black])
    (withcolor n[white,black] withpen pencircle scaled (2*(1pt-n)))
    shifted (.2pt,-.4pt);
endfor;
draw outlinetext.b
  ("$f:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}; f(x) = \log_a x,$")
  (withcolor black)
  (withcolor black);
\stopMPpage
```

[image]